# Notificaciónes en expo no estan funcionando bien

Tags: react-native, push-notification, expo

Estoy intentando personalizar el tono de mis notificaciones, pero cuando uso la API de Expo suenan las notificaciones que tengo por defecto en mi teléfono, según vi en Expo, hay que modificarlo en el archivo app.json de la siguiente manera:

```
{
...
"plugins": [
  [
    "expo-notifications",
    {
      "icon": "./assets/notification-icon.png",
      "color": "#E32726",
      "androidMode": "default",
      "sounds":[
        "./assets/notify.wav"
      ]
    }
  ]
]
...
}
```

Y también agregar los permisos:

```
{
...
"android": {
  ...
  "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
  "permissions": ["RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"]
}
...
}
```

Luego se configura el canal de las notificaciones:

```
Notifications.setNotificationChannelAsync('notificacion', {
  name: 'Notificaciones',
  importance: Notifications.AndroidImportance.MAX,
  sound: 'notify.wav'
}).then(result => {
  console.log("Todo bien");
  console.log(result);
}).catch(error => {
  console.log("Error");
  console.log(error);
});
```

Esta seria la configuración, pero cuando lo pruebo con la API de Expo genera la notificación pero se escucha con el tono que tengo en mi dispositivo, sera que estoy haciendo algo incorrecto?

Estoy usando Expo: 48.0.18